# Simple XML removing string between tags

Tags: php, xml

I have XML contains product. I need take from this XML: description, price, weight etc. 
When I opening XML using SimpleXML and printing i don't have text between tags. 
This is piece of my XML

```
<product id="30" currency="PLN" code_producer="M-1100/21">
    <producer id="1282294004" name="MAT lingerie" />
    <category id="1214553882" xml:lang="pol" name="BIUSTONOSZE/Półusztywniane" />
    <unit id="0" xml:lang="pol" name="szt." />
    <series id="4" xml:lang="pol" name="Basic Collection" />
    <card url="http://b2b.tiffanie.pl/product-pol-30-Sofia-biustonosz-polusztywniany-M-1100-21.html" />
    <description>
        <name xml:lang="eng">Sofia biustonosz półusztywniany M-1100/21</name>
        <name xml:lang="pol">Sofia biustonosz półusztywniany M-1100/21</name>
        <version name="czarny">
            <name xml:lang="eng">Sofia biustonosz półusztywniany M-1100/21</name>
            <name xml:lang="pol">czarny</name>
        </version>
        <long_desc xml:lang="eng">
            <span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #3f3229;">Delikatny biustonosz dla kobiet które cenią sobie komfort i wygodę. Biustonosz typu soft o perfekcyjnej konstrukcji pozwala zebrać biust jednocześnie doskonale, utrzymać go na miejscu. Miseczki zdobione są subtelnym kwiatowym haftem. Model posiada regulowane, odpinane ramiączka.</span>
        </long_desc>
        <long_desc xml:lang="pol">
            <span style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #3f3229;">Delikatny biustonosz dla kobiet które cenią sobie komfort i wygodę. Biustonosz typu soft o perfekcyjnej konstrukcji pozwala zebrać biust jednocześnie doskonale, utrzymać go na miejscu. Miseczki zdobione są subtelnym kwiatowym haftem. Model posiada regulowane, odpinane ramiączka.</span>
        </long_desc>
    </description>
```

**Result in print_r**

```
[description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [lang] => eng
                        )
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [lang] => pol
                        )
                )
        )

    [long_desc] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [lang] => eng
                        )
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [lang] => pol
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

How to use SimpleXML to read text between tags and save to object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing tag "`</product>`" at the end of the XML. Maybe was missing in the c&p

Any way this my test code using [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/xmlreader) works perfect and for me is the easiest way of read XML.

```
<?php

$input = file_get_contents('http://set4812.pl/web/1.xml');
$input = str_replace(['<![CDATA[', ']]>'], '', $input);

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->xml($input);
$r = xmlToArray($reader);
print_r($r);

function xmlToArray(XMLReader $xml){ 
    $array = []; 

    $i = 0; 
    while($xml->read()){ 
        if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT) {
            break; 
        } 

        if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && !$xml->isEmptyElement) { 
            unset($array[$i]);
            $array[$i]['name'] = $xml->name; 
            $array[$i]['values'] = xmlToArray($xml); 
            $array[$i]['attributes'] = getAttributesFromNode($xml);
            $i++; 
        } else if ($xml->isEmptyElement) { 
            $array[$i]['name'] = $xml->name; 
            $array[$i]['values'] = null; 
            $array[$i]['attributes'] = getAttributesFromNode($xml);
            $i++;
        } else if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::TEXT) {
            $array[$i]['values'] = $xml->value; 
        }
    }

    return $array; 
}

function getAttributesFromNode(XMLReader $xml)
{
    if(!$xml->hasAttributes) {
        return null;
    }

    $attributes = [];
    while($xml->moveToNextAttribute()) {
        $attributes[$xml->name] = $xml->value; 
    }
    
    return $attributes;
}
```

Comment: Not working for me i getting
                                                                            [attributes] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [xml:lang] => eng
                                                                                )

There is no description.
I not miss </product> i post small xml code, my code xml file is big.

Comment: As you can see my description values contains other nodes with "values" with text like "Sofia biustonosz półusztywniany M-1100/21" you are looking for that right?

Comment: Yes but my value is empty. I change declaration array from $array = []; to $array=array();

Comment: The code is based on 5.4. If you dont get any parse error you are on 5.4 so array() or [] not produce any changes. Can you copy my code and run in your box?

Comment: Copy paste take error 
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/dn187448/public_html/test/web/tablica.php on line 8
WHen i change $array = [];  to $array=array(); working but value is empty you can see result on http://set4812.pl/web/tablica.php

Comment: Ah ok, then you are using 5.3. Maybe then is a issue with you libxml, can you test in other box?

Comment: I update to php 5.4 on server and value is empty. I $reader->open("1.xml"); to open xml, when i use your string i can see value. You can see full xml http://set4812.pl/web/1.xml

Comment: I found the problem is reading the "<![CDATA[" encoded data, if you replace works.

Comment: I updated the response now works. I hope a upvote :D

Comment: You should not just remove the "<![CDATA[", this can break the XML. The problem is, that you only handle XMLReader::ELEMENT and XMLReader::TEXT, you need to handle XMLReader::CDATA, too.